# Mensaje de confirmación antes de eliminar elemento - Laravel 5.1

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un elemento con su respectivo botón de eliminar así:

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>['moneda.destroy', $moneda->id], 'method' => 'DELETE','id'=>'eliminar']) !!}
{!!Form::submit('Eliminar', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

El problema es cuando aparece el mensaje de confirmación. Antes de eliminar el elemento, no lo elimina, se queda ahí, y no hace nada.

Necesito que al darle aceptar a mi mensaje pueda eliminar el elemento.

Código:

```
$('#eliminar').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   url = $(this).parent().attr('action');

    BootstrapDialog.confirm(
      '¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el elemento?', function(result){

       if(result) {
            $.ajax(url);
       }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que en tu formulario usas el method `DELETE`, y en el js usas `$.ajax(url)`,  la función `$.ajax()` como en la documentación lo dice por dafault el método es `GET`, entonces así como lo tienes hace una petición tipo `GET` y no `DELETE`, entonces tienes que especificar dentro de tu `$.ajax()` algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
 url: myurl,
 type: 'DELETE'
});
```

Comment: Estimado, gracias por tu respuesta, lo probé como me dijiste y me sale un este error:  500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 4):

De esta manera solo detienes la ejecución del submit si la confirmación es negativa

```
$('#eliminar').submit(function(e){
     BootstrapDialog.confirm('Hi Apple, are you sure?', function(result){
            if(!result) {
               return false;
            }
     }); 
});
```

Comment: Estimado, gracias por tu respuesta, pero aún no funciona. Al momento de apretar aceptar en el mensaje no elimina el elemento. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 3):

Intenta con esto, a mí me funciona perfectamente para eliminar, espero a ti también te funcione.

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.marcas.destroy', $marca->ovt_idmarca)}}" onclick="
return confirm('Are you sure that you want to delete this item?')"
    class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"
        aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

Sé que el código no es muy limpio, ya que incluyo javascript dentro del HTML.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar y aviso como me fue

Comment: No funcionó muchas gracias de todas formas...

Answer (score 3):

Elimina lo de `.parent()` en la asignación del `action` a la variable `url`. Puesto que `$(this)` ya hace referencia al `form`. El `.parent()` está de más.

Comment: Gracias lo intentaré y aviso como me fue

Comment: Estimado, aun no funciona...no se que puede faltarme en el código. Muchas gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 3):

Te amplio una solución anterior que me pareció incompleta. O al menos para la forma correcta

Lo voy a hacer para usuarios, vos lo adaptaras para tu caso.

En route

```
Route::resource('users','UsersControllers');

Route::get('users/{id}/destroy',[
    'uses' => 'UsersControllers@destroy',
    'as' => 'users.destroy'
]);
```

En la vista donde esta el boton, icono o lo que sea que apretes para eliminar el objeto. Con este enlace llamas a la ruta con el nombre users.destroy y es atendida por l controlador y la funcion destroy

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('users.destroy',$us->id) }}" 
                        onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que deseas eliminarlo?')">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
                        </span>
                    </a>
```

En el controlador UsersControllers:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user= User::find($id);
    $user->delete();
    flash("Se ha eliminado ".$user->name." de forma exitosa!", 'danger')->important();

    return redirect()->route('users.index');

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito que el mensaje de confirmacion sea uno mas personalizado o sea con bootstrap y no un alert de javascript, entonces cómo podria ponerlo? tengo el codigo de script pero no funciona. Seria este:
$('#eliminar').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   url = $(this).attr('action');
   console.log(url);
    BootstrapDialog.confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el elemento?', function(result){

        if(result) {
            $.ajax(url);
        }

    });
});

Comment: cual es el motivo q necesitas usar js para mandar esa alerta? nunca use un    parecido en js para eso, pero por lo que puedo leer, basicamente hace lo mismo q hice usando onclick

Comment: Es mas que nada por solicitud de cliente que la alerta sea estéticamente mejor, es por eso que quiero usar bootstrap con jquery

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, tienes que mostrar el codigo del controller a la que esta asociada la url, ya que el error se origina en el servidor.

intentanto ayudar, si estas utilizando un controlador con la opcion --resource, el metodo que sirve para eliminar es: destroy($id), el cual recibe por get la id del recurso de esta forma: dominio.com/recurso/id, por lo tanto debes concatenar en la url un "/" mas el id. Tambien debes enviar como parametros en el ajax lo siguiente:

- _method=DELETE
- _token={{csrf_token()}}

Espero sea de tu ayuda.